# Hide Custom action in sharepoint 2013 ribbon

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, custom-actions

I want to hide the New Folder ribbon menu item for all document libraries. I have used this code but it is not working. What am I missing?

```
<CustomAction
 Id="CustomIdentifier.Ribbon.Documents.New.NewFolder.Hide"
 Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" RegistrationType="ContentType" RegistrationId="0x">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.NewFolder">
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to the settings of your document library and open **Advanced settings**. Then just disable the functionality for that :)

[image: Disable New Folder command]

You can also do this by code C#:

```
    docLibrary.EnableFolderCreation = false;
```

Comment: But I want to do it using customaction or hidecustomaction in sharepoint 2013.